# How to cast query to query of another interface to add constrainst based on that

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0

I wanted to implement a keyword search in C# EF Core (using .net core 3.0), that would go in my query building pipeline.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchKeyword) && query is IQueryable<IFullTextSearchable> queryFullTextSearchable)
{
      return queryFullTextSearchable.Where(x => x.FullSearchText == searchKeyword).Cast<TGetOutput>();
}
```

but after it goes through this and sorting/paging, then it throws an error that it can't translate the query. I was curious if it's even possible to evaluate such query in the database? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can do it using Dynamic Linq. Install the package from Nuget `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core -Version 1.0.19` and then just

```
return queryFullTextSearchable.Where($"FullSearchText == {searchKeyword}");
```

Not sure, however, if that check `query is IQueryable<IFullTextSearchable> queryFullTextSearchable` will work. If you know that the entity you're performing the query against is in fact `IFullTextSearchable`, you don't need that additional check.

Comment: What I know is that if searchKeyword is not null then the query has a column FullSearchText, but if not I don't know that, and this whole querying pipeline is used for other types so I can't just put that constraint on the TGetType that is coming in to the method. Is there a way to cast it and not break the db evaluation?

Comment: @HubertMijalski Can you show us the rest of the code, because it sounds like there could be ways of reworking that design?

Comment: hmm I actually managed to get it up and working with your tip with code like so
 `return query.Where("FullTextSearch.Contains(@0)", input.Keyword)`